# Image Upload When Connection is Good, Android (Background process)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, upload, android-workmanager

how to handle upload image on android during on the background When Connection is good?I have schema, When Connection is good it can upload, and when connection is bad it will store in the local and will be automatic reupload soon when connection is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WorkManager for this use case using a [constraint on the connection](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#constraints).

You should start recording in your datastore the data that you want to send to your backend, then enqueue a WorkRequest that is going to be executed when the connectivity is available.
Your worker "just" need to send the data to the backend.

To enqueue the worker you would use something like ([here I'm enqueuing it as a unique work request, to avoid duplication](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work)):

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()

val syncDataWorker = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SyncDataWorker>()
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .build()

val operation = WorkManager.getInstance(this)
        .enqueueUniqueWork(
                uniqueConferenceDataWorker,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                syncDataWorker)
```

Your work can then be done with a coroutineWorker ([a Worker class requires that all the content run synchronously](https://youtu.be/n9r5OCb7Qb8?t=462)):

```
class RefreshMainDataWork(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
        CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            // Retrieve data
            // Sync Data asynchronously with a suspended function
            Result.success()
        } catch (error: TitleRefreshError) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this also handle for you retries and lost of connectivity during the transmission. The worker is going to be stopped and rescheduled for when the connection is back.

It's difficult to go more in detail without knowing which data you need to synchronize and which libraries are you using. There's a sample on how to use `coroutineWorkers` in the [coroutine's codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/index.html?index=..%2F..index#10)

You can refer to [WorkManager's documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to see how to use it, also there's a simple codelab that shows how to use WorkManager. The codelab is available in [Java](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/) and in [Kotlin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/).

> [2019 version of ADSSched](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.adssched) (the event app for the Android Developer Summit) uses a similar setup to download updates on request, but it's more complex to follow as it uses Dagger to inject the reference to the use case to refresh the data. [Here's the commit](https://github.com/google/iosched/commit/74c6b69bbaaa928e45faf608dc37c27eb7dfd4b3).

Comment: can you give the example of this?

Comment: im sorry im newbie..but i'm little bit knows about your answer.i need how to apply this on activity..and how to call..im using java

Comment: so. on val constrain,syndataworker,and operation on dowork() method? and then i can create process on refresh main data work?

Comment: Take a look at the [Java codelab for WorkManager][1]. It should give you the basic understanding on how to use the library. That shows how to use a ViewModels to control and observe your `WorkRequest` from an Activity in a safe, lifecycle aware, way.


[1]: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/

Answer (score 0):

try this It is working for me :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class CheckConnectivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

boolean isConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, 
 false);
if(isConnected){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(context, "Internet Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }
}
```

Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.connect.broadcast"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <receiver android:exported="false"
      android:name=".CheckConnectivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: is that auto check?i think it's not auto check.because it will run at the background.